# python shelve dbm.error?

Tags: python, shelve

I'm trying to add a dict of dicts to a shelve file:

```
>>> d = shelve.open('index.shelve')
>>> d
<shelve.DbfilenameShelf object at 0x21965f0>
>>> print(list(d.keys()))
[]
>>> d['index'] = index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/bns/rma/local/python/lib/python3.1/shelve.py", line 124, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)] = f.getvalue()
_dbm.error: cannot add item to database
```

index is somewhat large but not huge. It is essentially an array of floats:

```
>>> len(index)
219
>>> a = [ index[k][k1] for k in index for k1 in index[k] ]
>>> len(a)
59995
>>> all([ type(x) is float for x in a ])
True
```

What is this error? Also, is there somewhere within the module or the module docs I should be looking to get more info on what the error represents? The error message is not very informative, at least to me :).

Comment: I should have also said that I'm using python 3.1.2.

Comment: Can you set elements of the shelve at all? For example, if `index` is an int, do you get the same crash? What about a dict, or a smaller dict of dicts?

Comment: I should have mentioned that ... it appears to work fine for a small list or dict that I tested it with.

Comment: I'm interested in the boundary between a not-crashing version and a crashing version. Can you find a case where a dict with N entries doesn't crash, but N+1 does?

Comment: Good point. I will try to test this soon and post back.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had the same problem with the dbm module, it is reproducable in my codebase but I can't reproduce it in an isolated test.

My impression is that there is a lock that prevents writing when the database is being read. In my case, the db is ~200Kb, with ~10 keys and inserting a `time.sleep(1)` would solve the problem, hinting at some async process not finished at the moment of the `db[key] = value`.

Comment: Here are links to similar issues: http://issues.roundup-tracker.org/issue1017587 and http://markmail.org/message/joqtmews3iwkcvtu#query:+page:1+mid:joqtmews3iwkcvtu+state:results